# Getting an integer value from a byte-string in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I am implementing a RSA and AES file encryption program. So far, I have RSA and AES implemented. What I wish to understand however is , if my AES implementation uses a 16 byte key (obtained by os.urandom(16)) how could I get an integer value from this to encrypt with the RSA ?

In essence, if I have a byte string like 
 `` b',\x84\x9f\xfc\xdd\xa8A\xa7\xcb\x07v\xc9`\xefu\x81' ``

How could I obtain an integer from this byte string (AES key) which could subsequently be used for encryption using (RSA)?

Flow of encryption

Encrypt file (AES Key) -> Encrypt AES key (using RSA)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR use `from_bytes` and `to_bytes` to implement OS2IP and I2OSP respectively.

---

For secure encryption, you don't directly turn the AES key into a number. This is because [raw RSA is inherently insecure in many many ways](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/1172) (the list is not complete at the time of writing).

First you need to random-pad your key bytes to obtain a byte array that will represent a number close to the modulus. Then you can perform the byte array conversion to a number, and only then should you perform modular exponentiation. Modular exponentiation will also result in a number, and you need to turn that number into a statically sized byte array with the same size as the modulus (in bytes).

All this is standardized in the PKCS#1 RSA standard. In v2.2 there are two schemes specified, known as [PKCS#1 v1.5 padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2) and [OAEP padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1). The first one is pretty easy to implement, but is more vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. OAEP is also vulnerable, but less so. You will however need to follow the implementation hints to the detail, especially during unpadding.

To circle back to your question, the number conversions are called the octet string to integer primitive ([OS2IP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-4.2)) and the integer to octet string primitive ([I2OSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-4.1)). These are however not mathematical operations that you need to perform: they just describe how to represent how to *encode* the number as statically sized, big endian, unsigned integer.

Say that `keysize` is the key size (modulus size) in bits and `em` is the `bytes` or `bytearray` representing the padded key, then you'd just perform:

```
m = int.from_bytes(em, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

for OS2IP where `m` will be the input for modular exponentiation and back using:

```
k = (keysize + 8 - 1) / 8
em = m.to_bytes(k, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

for I2OSP.

And you will have to perform the same two operations for decryption...

Comment: If im understanding this correctly, you simply pad the number slightly and use this for encryption (as seen above) ( How is this then returned to its original representation for decryption ? And is using I20SP much of a downgrade in comparison to OS2IP ?

Comment: You don't pad numbers, you pad (octet) strings; after that you can revert it to a number. I2OSP and OS2IP are an encoding and a decoding method that together form a codec. They are opposites but they are are not competing against each other.

Comment: Sorry I get it now. I wanted to send the encrypted AES key as the filename or at the end of the file as the program im writing is non-dependent on a secure platform. Using OS2IP and 120SP *should* be secure enough for this. Also , you say keysize (the n or modulus size), in bytes ?

Comment: In my code `keysize` is in bits and `k` is the same value in bytes (rounded up of course). And without the padding that RSA requires, just number conversion **is not** secure; why do you think I write these things in my answer? If you want to avoid it use the RSA-KEM route suggested by kelalaka. Then you need to implement or find a library for the KDF of course, but hey, nobody claims crypto is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To literally interpret the byte-string as an integer (which you should be able to do; python integers can get arbitrarily large), you could just sum up the values, shifted the appropriate number of bits:

```
bytestr = b',\x84\x9f\xfc\xdd\xa8A\xa7\xcb\x07v\xc9`\xefu\x81'
le_int = sum(v << (8 * i) for i, v in enumerate(bytestr))
# = sum([44, 33792, 10420224, 4227858432, 949187772416, 184717953466368, 18295873486192640, 12033618204333965312, 3744689046963038978048, 33056565380087516495872, 142653246714526242615328768, 62206486974090358813680992256, 7605903601369376408980219232256, 4847495895272749231323393057357824, 607498732448574832538068070518751232, 171470411456254147604591110776164450304])
# = 172082765352850773589848323076011295788
```

That would be a little-endian interpretation; a big-endian interpretation would just start reading from the other side, which you could do with `reversed()`:

```
be_int = sum(v << (8 * i) for i, v in enumerate(reversed(bytestr)))
# = sum([129, 29952, 15663104, 1610612736, 863288426496, 129742372077568, 1970324836974592, 14627691589699371008, 3080606260309495119872, 306953821386526938890240, 203099537695257701350637568, 68396187170517260188176613376, 19965496953594613073573075484672, 3224903126980615597407612954476544, 685383185326597246966025515457052672, 58486031814536298407767510652335161344])
# = 59174659937086426622213974601606591873
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer and something I did'nt think of using, cheers !

Comment: This is unnecessarily difficult. The `int` class contains methods for going back and forth between integers and byte arrays. See `int.to_bytes(...)` and `int.from_bytes(...)` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types)

Comment: Well, arguably it is better than the code I saw that performed the actual *exponentiation* & multiplication - per byte - instead of the shifting. Many people don't seem to realize that I2OSP is just a description on how to represent an integer in memory :)